# For loops using grepl

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, if-statement, grepl

I am trying to use a for loop to run through a data frame, see if an observation contains a certain string in a column (i.e., it should contain "no law" in the column *Content*), and generate values in a different column based on the outcome.

If it does contain the string, which is identified by the outcome of the `grepl` function being *True*, then the observation should have 'Permissive' in the *Effectrp* column; otherwise, it should say 'Restrictive'.

I'm not quite sure what I'm doing wrong... Any help would be appreciated!

```
for (i in 1:nrow(ldb)){
  if (grepl('no law', ldb$Content[i], ignore.case = TRUE)) == TRUE {
    ldb$Effectrp[i] = 'Permissive'
  } else {
    lab$EffectTR[i] = 'Restrictive'
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar to the answer I wrote to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62517201/mapping-the-topic-of-the-review-in-r/62519028#62519028) question.

The only potential problem I can see is typos in the `else` part. You wrote `lab$EffectTR` when earlier your dataframe was named `ldb` and the column was named `Effectrp`. Not sure if this is intentional.

**Clarification of the redundancy thing:**

You don't need the `== TRUE` in your `if` statement. I think of it like this. Right now you have:

```r
if (grepl(check if my pattern is found in Content) == TRUE) {
    do something
}
```

grepl returns `TRUE/FALSE`, so let's say `"no law"` is found in `Content`, then grepl evaluates to `TRUE`, producing:

```
if (TRUE == TRUE) {
    do something
}
```

If we continue evaluating the parentheses, we know that indeed, `TRUE == TRUE`, so this reduces to:

```
if (TRUE) {
    do something
}
```

This is what we want. However, the extra check `TRUE == TRUE` is unnecessary when you could just use the output from grepl like so:

```
if (grepl(check if my pattern is found in Content) {
    do something
}
```

This will evaluate to:

```
if (TRUE) {
    do something
}
```

the same thing as before, but you're skipping the redundant `== TRUE` step. i.e. the if statement will run, because the thing inside the parentheses is `TRUE` in a quite literal sense.

Hope that makes more sense! It was confusing to me when I first learned it as well.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by just saying ```if(TRUE)```? I didn't quite get that. Also, thank you for noticing the spelling error!

Answer (score 6):

You shouldn't even need a for loop for this, as `grepl` will return a vector if applied to a vector.  You could try something like

```r
ldb$Effectrp <- 'Restrictive'
lbd$Effectrp[grepl('no law', ldb$Content, ignore.case = TRUE)] <- 'Permissive'
```

(and, as mentioned in the previous answer, be careful about the typos in your data frame and column names.)

Comment: @MartinGal oops, yeah.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Using `base R`:

```r
ldb$EffectRP <- sapply(ldb$Content, 
                       function(x) if (grepl("no law", x, ignore.case = TRUE)) {"Permissive"} else {"Restrictive"} )
```

Using `dplyr` and `stringr`:

```r
ldb %>%
  mutate(EffectRP2 = ifelse(str_detect(Content, "no law"), "Permissive", "Restrictive"))
```

Those options return:

```
   Content    EffectRP   EffectRP2
1      law Restrictive Restrictive
2   no law  Permissive  Permissive
3      law Restrictive Restrictive
4   no law  Permissive  Permissive
5      law Restrictive Restrictive
6      law Restrictive Restrictive
7   no law  Permissive  Permissive
8   no law  Permissive  Permissive
9   no law  Permissive  Permissive
10  no law  Permissive  Permissive
```